# Session cookie and improving page load time

Tags: cookies

I'm thinking about my project where information from data base will be displayed on the website after searching where client will be able to define various search criteria.

And my question is: Is it good idea to use session cookies for example when client changes criteria but part of it still is the same? Does it improve page load time or using cookies in this way doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to store data on a browser is to use localStorage with a much larger capacity it is far better the cookies.

Just use `localStorage.setItem("data",dataJsonOrValue));`
And `localStorage.getItem("data");

To increase the speed of your page you just need to first search from your `localStorage` if the criteria is changed a little and you feel no more data fetching from DB is needed(You'll need to define an algorithm which finds that search criteria has changed just a little).